# Use directive inside another directive

Tags: angular-directive, angular7

How can I insert a directive rule inside another directive definition?
I have defined this directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[appCardBody]"
})
export class CardBodyDirective {
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    el.nativeElement.style.width = "95%";
    el.nativeElement.style.marginTop = "20px";
  }
}
```

and I use this directive in this way:

```
<div
   appCardBody
   fxLayout="row"
   fxLayoutAlign="space-between center"
   fxLayout.lt-md="column"></div>
```

How can I include the fx* attributes (from angular flex-layout directives) directly inside my appCardBody directive?

I have already tried forcing the elements like this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[appCardBody]"
})
export class CardBodyDirective {
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    el.nativeElement.style.width = "95%";
    el.nativeElement.style.marginTop = "20px";
    el.nativeElement.fxLayout = "row"
    // the other proprieties
  }
}
```

But in this way it does not work.
Any suggestion?